# NuSMV Realtime CTL

Tags: ctl, nusmv

I'm using NuSMV and i'm trying to write a Real Time CTL property.
I would like to know if there is a way to set the steps from a state, like:
`((s.state = on) ABG (0..5 s.state = off))`

Is read as: `if (s.state=on) is true`, from this state and for other 5 steps the property `(s.state= off) is true`.
I tried to write something like this but it doesn't work. Can you help me?

Otherwise, is it possible to check the same property starting from a state that isn't the first?

Answer (score 0):

**Question.** write *`if (s.state=on) is true`, from this state and for other 5 steps the property `(s.state= off) is true.`*

**CTL.**

```
CTLSPEC AG ((s.state = on) -> 
            ((AX s.state = off) &
             (AX AX s.state = off) &
             (AX AX AX s.state = off) &
             (AX AX AX AX s.state = off) &
             (AX AX AX AX AX s.state = off)
           ));
```

With this formula, you test whether it is true that each time you hit `s.state = on` condition `s.state = off` will be true for at least *5 states* following the current one, regardless of your path choice.

The initial `AG` ensures that this property must hold anywhere on the execution path, and not only in the initial state.

**Real Time CTL.**

From *nusmv mailing list*:

```
((s.state = on) ABG (1..5 s.state = off))
```

---

**Note:** *the rest of your question isn't clear to me, so please if there is still some unanswered part just edit your question and clarify a bit.*

Comment: This is a CTL formula, i have to write it in Real Time CTL where the number of steps are specified as: `int_number..int_number `
If i write this : `EBF 0..49 b.efficiency = 50 ` i'm checking that from the state 0 to the state 49 the efficiency is 50. But, i would like to know if there is a way to check a property not from a state (like 0,1,2...) but from a state where a condition is true, like :
`EBF (s.state = on)..49 b.efficiency = 50 ` that is readed as : from the state where `(s.state = on)` and for the next 49 steps, `b.efficiency = 50`
I hope that it's clear now

Comment: @Desmond can you edit your question and add the model you are referring to?